# How to get values of two columns only when both column values are present using bash script

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sh

1

2

3   5

4   6

9

I have two columns, if 2nd column contain no values then skip the row  else I want result like two column values only  when both column values are present

sample output

3 5

4 6

Comment: Your question is not clear. Just what exactly is your difficulty? please use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43079525/edit) for fix format

Comment: now understand..???

Comment: I edited again I want to get two columns values if both column contain values elase skip that row

Comment: try with `NF>1` or `NF==2`

Comment: cat temp.txt | awk '{print ; NF>1 || NF==2}'  I tried this but same result I am getting in the above question

Comment: the `\d+ \d+` is your friend.

Comment: cat temp.txt | awk '{print ; \d+ \d+}' syntax error.......

Comment: @arunsoman `cat temp.txt | awk 'NF==2'` XD .....  `awk 'NF==2' temp.txt` better

Comment: I am sorry to say ,I am getting same previous output

Answer (score 0):

If a solution using `grep` is acceptable:

```
grep -v " " input
grep -E '[[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ awk '/[0-9]+ [0-9]+/' temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NF==2' file
3 5
4 6
```

`NF` is the number of fields in awk. Above command prints records where field count equals to 2.

Answer (score 0):

For bash only you could try:

```
while read -r -a nums
do
  (( ${#nums[*]} == 2 )) && echo "${nums[@]}"
done<input_file
```